# Convert spring mvc controller method for servlet to portlet

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I have one controller written in spring mvc for servlet environment. Now I want to convert controller to make it work for portlet environment. I am using spring mvc for portlet.

Below is the method snippet,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
  Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);
  model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
  return "displayOwner";
}
```

Can anyone please guide me how can i convert this controller method written for servlet environment to portlet environment? 
I want to change RequestMapping to RenderMapping

Answer (score 0):

This may be delayed reply, but if you ever come back here then you can infer something (or you might have already).

`@PathVariable` is not valid in Spring Portlet environment, because you can't map `Action`, `Render` and `Resource` URLs to `Controller`s methods unlike `REST` urls

If you want to convert the Servlet Controller to a Portlet Controller, then your code should read as below

```
@RequestMapping(params="anyIdentifier")
public String findOwner(@RequestParam String ownerId, Model model) {
  Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);
  model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
  return "displayOwner";
}
```

`@RequestMapping` still holds good in Portlet environment, but there are some specific annotations you can use based on the portlet urls.

- `@ActionMapping` - for Action Urls and return should be void. It has no effect though you return a `View` or `ModelAndView` beacause of Portlet's 2 step execution
- `@RenderMapping` - for Render Urls and return can be a `View` or `ModelAndView`. This always follows the `@ActionMapping`
- `@ResourceMapping` - for Resource Urls and return can be a `Void`, `View` or `ModelAndView` -  Mostly used in ajax calls.